# Trying to create a compressed bitmap in png format getting 2 errors

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a bitmap that is compressed.

I'm trying to use the bitmaps compress methed to save a compress bitmap in a Outputstream, then use decode stream to create a bitmap object from the Output stream.

My code has the following errors
1. methed toByteArray is undefined for OutputStream
2. Cannot initate the type outputstream.

My code

```
inputStream=assetManager.open(sb.toString());  
Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

// this line produces a error saying cannot imitate OutputSream
OutputStream out=new OutputStream();

b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,out);

// this ;ine has a error saying method does not exist
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `OutputStream` to this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

There is no `toByteArray()` in the `OutputStream`.

In the compress method of the inputstream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream will still be accepted cause it is a subclass of the `OutputStream`
```